# Basic AngularJS Form Validation is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm using basic example from W3School and trying to validate AngularJS form. But in any browser form is not getting validated. Any suggestions on the same?

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>

    <p>Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
        </span>
    </p>

    <p>Email:<br>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
        </span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
    </p>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript pertaining to this example?

Comment: Your problem is you got the example from W3Schools :)
Post your JavaScript code so we can help you.

Comment: No, I do not have any...

Comment: I tried with my code to and also tried with different code, but not luck :(

Comment: The above code is working http://plnkr.co/edit/3BRuOCZa6R1ifXPecKwx?p=preview whats the issue?

Comment: I'm using $routeProvider service when I click on my contact us page it is not working at all. It also shows all hidden messages. I'm using XAMMP local server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include ng-app and ng-controller to your form. also declare the app and controller in a separate js file.

Comment: I have already declare ng-app for my HTML. And I do not need any ng-controller as I'm not going to use that for any reason.